# I want to dynamically change value of my button from a form input filled by the user using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, button, addeventlistener, getelementbyid

A user fill a form (to customize a product) and I want to take his output to dynamically change info of my button.

I've succeed to target element of the user but I can change the value of my button....

My form :

```
   <form>
       <fieldset>
          <legend>Selecting elements</legend>
          <p>
             <label>Select type : </label>
             <select id="type" name="type">
               <option> X </option>
               <option> Palleitte </option>
             </select>

          </p>
       </fieldset>
    </form>
```

My button :

```
  <button name="julien" class="snipcart-add-item" id="my-button"
    data-item-id="{{ product.identifier }}"
    data-item-name="{{ product.name }}"
    data-item-price="20.00"



    data-item-custom2-name="Type"
    data-item-custom2-options="Cachet|Palleitte"
    data-item-custom2-value=""

    data-item-custom3-name="Quantité"
    data-item-custom3-options="100g|200g|500g|1kg|100kg"
    data-item-custom3-value="500g"
    >
    ADD TO THE CART 
  </button>
```

MY JS CODE SO FAR :

```
<script>

    document.getElementById("type").addEventListener("click", function(){
      const x = document.getElementById("my-button");
      console.log(x);

      console.log(document.getElementById("type"));
      document.getElementById("my-button").innerText = "change by the input of user";
});

</script>
```

I expect to change the value of my button : data-item-custom2-value="" by the value of what the user fill in the form, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is fine but the javascript needs some changes as follow

```js
    document.getElementById("type").addEventListener("change", function(elem){
      var e = document.getElementById("type");
      var selectedValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
      document.getElementById("my-button").innerText = selectedValue;
});
```

```html
 <form>
       <fieldset>
          <legend>Selecting elements</legend>
          <p>
             <label>Select type : </label>
             <select id="type" name="type">
               <option> X </option>
               <option> Palleitte </option>
             </select>

          </p>
       </fieldset>
    </form>
  <button name="julien" class="snipcart-add-item" id="my-button"
    data-item-id="{{ product.identifier }}"
    data-item-name="{{ product.name }}"
    data-item-price="20.00"



    data-item-custom2-name="Type"
    data-item-custom2-options="Cachet|Palleitte"
    data-item-custom2-value=""

    data-item-custom3-name="Quantité"
    data-item-custom3-options="100g|200g|500g|1kg|100kg"
    data-item-custom3-value="500g"
    >
  </button>
```

Comment: thank you very much ! Just i want to affect "selectedValue" to the champ "data-item-custom2-value" in order to have something like that after "data-item-custom2-value = selectedValue". The problem is that when I run this :  ```     console.log(document.getElementById("my-button")); ```
It retreive the whole HTML code for the button but I didn't succed to access the value I want : i tried this for example : ```      console.log(document.getElementById("my-button").data-item-custom2-name);
```. Sorry to bother you again.... but thank !